# $\gcd$ proof relating to $\gcd$'s associativity and commutativity (I think)

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove that the $\gcd(a,b,c)$ = $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$.

I think it has something to do with $\gcd$'s being able to be represented by a linear combination (that is $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by > 0$, for some integer $x$ and $y$).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one proof:

If $d$ divides each of $a,b,c$ then $d|\gcd(a,b)$ and $d|c$.  Conversely if $d|\gcd(a,b)$ and $d|c$ then $d$ divides each of $a,b,c$.  Hence any number which divides $a$, $b$ and $c$ must also divide both $\gcd(a,b)$, $c$, and the converse is also true.

Since their divisors are identical, the greatest common divisor will also be the same, and we have $\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)$.

Comment: That's essentially the fact that set intersection is associative: $D(a,b,c)=D(a) \cap D(b) \cap D(c) = (D(a) \cap D(b)) \cap D(c)$ = $D(a,b) \cap D(c) = D(\gcd(a,b))\cap D(c) = D(\gcd(a,b),c)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
d|\gcd(a,b,c) & \Longleftrightarrow d|a,b,c\\
&\Longleftrightarrow d|a,b\text{ and }d|c\\
&\Longleftrightarrow d|\gcd(a,b),c\\
&\Longleftrightarrow d|\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c).
\end{align*}$$